# Any functor F equipped with a natural weak equivalence to or from the identity functor is homotopical by the 2-of-3 property.

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Any functor Q equipped with a natural weak equivalence to
or from the identity functor is homotopical by the 2-of-3 property:
if any two of gf, g and f are in W then so is the third

WHY?

Homotopical functor is a functor preserving weak equivalences.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. If $f:x\to y$ is a weak equivalence and $\eta_y:  y\to Qy$ is a weak equivalence then $\eta_y \circ f$ is a weak equivalence. So $Qf: Qx\to Qy$ is a weak equivalence.

Comment: You're drawing the naturality square for $f$ in your head to get the final conclusion. I could imagine the OP could have used that detail.